# How to output Fiducials to Pick&Place but exclude them from BOM in Altium?

Tags: altium, manufacturing, bom

In Altium, the (not so) obvious way was to set the Fiducial component type to "Standard (No BOM)", but this also prevents them from showing up in the Pick&Place output.

I could set the type so "Standard" and manually add a filter in the BOM each time, but that is far from ideal. The filter does not support using a negative mask (like: "hide all where designator contains FD*) and its cumbersome.
The preferred way would be if the behavior is tied to the Fiducial component itself.

Does the typical manufacturer actually care if Fiducials appear in the P&P data or not? (the last one cried at me for not having them in the P&P data). But isn't the same extra step required if you have a panelized design with "extra" Fiducials on the panel which have no reference coordinate with respect to the board?

Am I missing some easy way to achieve it?
How do you do it?

Comment: There's an exclude from BOM checkbox somewhere, if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is certainly not a general question and would be CAD package specific. One choice I have used is to extract BOM from schematic but manually add the fiducials to the layout database so that they will appear in the layout export to P&P data. But that method is also certainly specific to the CAD package that I use.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: This wasn't meant as a generic question, thus the [Altium] tag. Maybe I should specifically point it out anyway.

Comment: You should point out the specific CAD package in the question. Hiding that in the tag is not really useful as I,  and surely many others, come here looking at questions, not tags. Recent stylistic site behavior also makes the grey text of tags very easy to miss as well.

Comment: Would a project variant help there? I know that in variant you can mark component as not fitted , and it wont appear in BOM but not sure for P&P.

Comment: @Haris778: Non-fitted components are excluded from the Pick&Place data.

Comment: Last time I made a board I post-processed some of the outputs like the BOM with a custom python script.   I will probably never again _not_ do so; it simplified so many annoyances especially when speaking to multiple vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Just tick the "Include Standard (NO BOM) items" box in the Pick and Place Setup dialog. If you have other items of this type which you don't want in your pick and place file (e.g. mounting holes), you can filter them out by clicking the funnel icon in a column header.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to do but annoying.

In schematic editor, select it as Standard (No BOM)
And in pcb editor, select it as Standard

But remember everytime you import changes in pcb, just untick the fiducial type change.